# Why error show in debug, but not in release?

Tags: mfc

My system: win10
Visual C++ 2015.     I start a new mfc program, add 1 button, add code:

```
HDC hdc;
bool b = false;
CPrintDialog pdlg(b);
CPrintDialog ppdlg(b);
if (pdlg.DoModal() == IDOK) {
    CDC printerset;
    hdc = pdlg.CreatePrinterDC();
    printerset.Attach(hdc);
    printerset.SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
    printerset.m_bPrinting = true;
    DOCINFO di;
    ::ZeroMemory(&di, sizeof(DOCINFO));
    di.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);

    wchar_t wstr[1024];
    char str[1024];
    int x;
    memset(str, 0, 1024);

    di.lpszDocName = L"abc";

    CSize size, psize;
    psize.cx = printerset.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX);
    psize.cy = printerset.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY);
    size.cx = psize.cx / 300;
    size.cy = psize.cy / 300;
    printerset.SetViewportExt(size);
    int pfin = printerset.StartDoc(&di);
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    printerset.StartPage();
    printerset.MoveTo(0, 0);
    printerset.LineTo(100, 200);
    printerset.EndPage();
    printerset.EndPage();
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    printerset.EndDoc();
    DeleteDC(printerset.Detach());
    DeleteDC(hdc);
    if (pdlg.m_pd.hDC != 0)
    {
        DeleteDC(pdlg.m_pd.hDC);
        pdlg.m_pd.hDC = 0;
    }
}
```

[image: My Dialog]

[image: Error Dialog]

after use the button, the alarm dialog always shows when I quit the program in debug, but never shows in release.
I can't find way out.

Help me please~~!

Comment: Press "Retry", that breaks into the debugger, then inspect the call stack to find out which one of your lines caused the eror. Inspecting the MFC source code that triggered the error dialog might also help. [Edit] your question and tell us more and we can help you. Also show your complete `OnWhateverButton` function and not only a snippet of it.

Comment: *"dialog always shows when I quit the program in debug, but never shows in release. I can't find way out."* - It's a **debug** assertion, that verifies preconditions in a debug configuration. In a release configuration debug assertions compile to nothing, hence you don't see the assertion dialog. The bug is still there. Press *"Retry"* to break into the debugger. This will take you right to the line that verified the precondition.

Comment: Is the code you posted the exact copy of the code you are using? I took time and used your code in my test app and I have no problem. No assertion.
If the posted code is the same, the problem exists outside of it and is caused by calling Windows API on the window with an invalid handle.
How are you quitting your app, by pressing OK or different way?

Comment: I have get another way in use PRINTDLG.  Thank you. As for the problem, it could be that my visual studio or Windows is not updated.

Comment: *"it could be that my visual studio or Windows is not updated."* - No. There is a bug in **your** code, that you need to fix. If you don't know what debug assertions are or how to use a debugger effectively, ask a senior member on your team for help.